# Why does it called dynamic binding, rather than static binding?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I'm new to Java and I have struck with some doubt. For example, consider the expression like:

```
a.method()
a.method("string")
```

people call them "dynamic dispatch". But I'm sure that the type checker makes sure that the methods named `method()`,`method(String a)` available for object `a`.

But why does it called "dynamic"? It isn't static call? Since the compiler found that already?

Comment: *Who* exactly is calling this dynamic dispatch? Maybe there's more context (such as the method being overridden, as that part *is* dynamic.

Comment: The overloaded determination is *static*, but the potential polymorphic code is *dynamic*

Comment: See [Wikipedia: Dynamic Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) "This [subtype-polymorphic] object-oriented feature allows substituting a particular implementation using the same interface, and therefore it enables polymorphism." - That being said, I don't hear it come up in Java parlance much ..

Comment: Nobody calls it "dynamic dispatch", let me assure you. Unless they don't know what they are talking about.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Why not? I would argue that Single Dispatch is merely a specialization of Dynamic Dispatch.

Comment: @pst The dispatch on the arguments inside parentheses is not dynamic, and that's what OP is asking about, isn't it?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik If that conclusion is reached. Java, being Single Dispatch (as opposed to Multiple Dispatch like CLOS and the like), only considers the *receiver*. Then again, so does JavaScript. And I don't think people argue against JavaScript being Dynamic Dispatch ..

Comment: @pst Single dispatch is the norm in pretty much any language people call OOP. Multimethods are a completely different ballgame since there is no concept of "receiver" or of method ownership by classes.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik But Dynamic Dispatch isn't limited to MD/MM, so we're back to what is Dynamic Dispatch (in Java) :) Note that I *agree* with Rohit's answer about the posted code *not* showing dynamic dispatch so the OP is all confused.

Comment: @pst No point in arguing when we obviously agree on everything except on what OP actually asked :) Yes of course, Java is a dynamic dispatch language, but OP asked whether the dispatch of `method` on its parenthesized arguments can be called "dynamic". Both of us agree that no, it can't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example that you have posted will not use dynamic dispatch. You have posted an example of `Method Overloading`. And decision of method invocation in case of `Overloading` is done at compile time. It is on the compiler to decide which method will be invoked based on the `formal parameters` and the `actual arguments` passed.

---

`Dynamic Binding` comes into play when you are working with `Method Overriding`, where the decision of which method will actually be invoked is delayed till runtime.

For e.g: -

```
class A {
    public void demo() { }
}

class B extends A {
    public void demo() { }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        a.demo();   // B class method will be invoked.

        A obj = new A();
        obj.demo();  // A class method will be invoked.
    }
}
```

The decision of which method is invoked is decided on the basis of which class instance the particular reference is pointing to, And that is only known at `runtime`. And hence `Dynamic Dispatch`.

Answer (score 1):

The code you are showing doesn't **express dynamic dispatch(binding)**.look at the below code.

```
class Super {
  public void method() {}
}

class Sub extends Super {
  public void method() {}

  public static void main(String... args) {
    Super inst = new Sub();
    inst.method(); //Sub's method() would be invoked.(Express's Dynamic Dispatch)
  }
}
```